# How do I make a term more proportionate?

Tags: amsmath, fontsize, mathtools

The following code:

```
In order to find $A_{0}^1$:
\begin{equation}
A_{0}^{1} = \lim_{z \rightarrow -1}\dfrac{d^0}{dz^0}\Bigg[\dfrac{(z+1)z}{(z+1)(z-2)}\Bigg]=\lim_{z \rightarrow -1}\dfrac{z}{(z-2)}=\dfrac{1}{3}
\end{equation}
And in order to find $A_{0}^2$:
\begin{equation}
A_{0}^2 = \lim_{z \rightarrow 2} \dfrac{d^0}{dz^0}\Bigg[\dfrac{(z-2)z}{(z+1)(z-2)}\Bigg]=\lim_{z \rightarrow 2}\dfrac{z}{(z+1)}=\dfrac{2}{3}
\end{equation}
From (38) we get:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{3}\Bigg[\dfrac{1}{z+1}\Bigg]+\dfrac{2}{3}\Bigg[\dfrac{1}{z-2}\Bigg]
\end{equation}
where we have that $\Bigg[\dfrac{1}{z+1}\Bigg]$ can be rewritten as $\dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{1}{1-\Big(-\dfrac{1}{z}\Big)}$
```

gives me the following:

[image]

The following is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1.5in, top=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\onehalfspacing

\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Arg}{Arg}

\begin{document}

\title{Homework Chapter 5}
\author{}

\maketitle
```

How can I make the term shown after rewritten on the last line more proportionate?

Comment: (You don't need to provide 13 lines of code and 20 lines of preamble when your problem is in the 13th line.)  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "more proportionate".  But if you're wanting the final 1/z to be smaller, why not switch out of dfrac, which is "displaystyle frac"?

Comment: why are you using `\dfrac`  in display mode it does nothing ( it is the same as `\frac`) and in the denominator it just forces it to use an over-sized fraction.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Next time I'll use 20 lines of preamble and 1 line of code. I ended up using 1/(1-(1/z))

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Notice how the accepted answer only needed one package, and 2 lines of code for the "can be rewritten as part".  So you could have presented your entire problem with 9 lines of code (3 of them blank).  That's what I meant by providing too much code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `1-(-z^{-1})`.

I also made several fixes:

- removed several redundant parentheses;
- `\Bigg` is too big and wrong, it should be `\biggl` and `\biggr`;
- also `\Big` is wrong in the same way and unnecessary;
- the cross-reference should use `\eqref` and not the explicit number.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

In order to find $A_{0}^1$
\begin{equation}\label{A01}
A_{0}^{1}
  = \lim_{z \rightarrow -1}\frac{d^0}{dz^0}\biggl[\frac{(z+1)z}{(z+1)(z-2)}\biggr]
  = \lim_{z \rightarrow -1}\frac{z}{z-2}=\frac{1}{3}
\end{equation}
And in order to find $A_{0}^2$
\begin{equation}
A_{0}^2
  = \lim_{z \rightarrow 2} \frac{d^0}{dz^0}\biggl[\frac{(z-2)z}{(z+1)(z-2)}\biggr]
  = \lim_{z \rightarrow 2} \frac{z}{z+1}=\frac{2}{3}
\end{equation}
From~\eqref{A01} we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3}\biggl[\frac{1}{z+1}\biggr]+\frac{2}{3}\biggl[\frac{1}{z-2}\biggr]
\end{equation}
where we have that $\dfrac{1}{z+1}$ can be rewritten as 
$\dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{1}{1-(-z^{-1})}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]